# including a scope in spotipy

Tags: scope, spotipy

I'm using spotipy to extract information from a playlist (specifically the ten most listened songs by the user) and I'm asked for a scope. I'm not sure where I should include the scope so that it gives me permission. I leave the code that I have written in case someone could help me.

```
import requests
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials

scope= 'user-top-read'
client_credentials_manager = 
SpotifyClientCredentials(client_id='6b78bf9e892b4e8184c8e906885108bc', client_secret='3c2c0c7374374ab98062f342860369a5')
sp = spotipy.Spotify(client_credentials_manager = client_credentials_manager(scope=scope)

playlist_link = "https://open.spotify.com/playlist/75bo0xrhJrSf0Gf0iqEPuS"
playlist_URI = playlist_link.split("/")[-1].split("?")[0]
track_uris = [x["track"]["uri"] for x in sp.playlist_tracks(playlist_URI)["items"]]

for track in sp.playlist_tracks(playlist_URI)["items"]:

     #URI
     track_uri = track["track"]["uri"]

     #Track name
     track_name = track["track"]["name"]

     #Top ten artists
     artist_uri = track["track"]["artists"][0]["uri"]
     artist_info = sp.current_user_top_artists(limit=10, offset=0, time_range='medium_term')
     print(artist_info)
```

Answer (score 0):

A list of scopes (and their endpoints/i.e. what a particular scope covers), can be found at https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/concepts/scopes#user-library-read).

List of Scopes

**Images**

- ugc-image-upload

**Spotify Connect**

- user-read-playback-state
- user-modify-playback-state
- user-read-currently-playing

**Playback**

- app-remote
- control streaming

**Playlists**

- playlist-read-private
- playlist-read-collaborative
- playlist-modify-private
- playlist-modify-public

**Follow**

- user-follow-modify
- user-follow-read

**Listening History**

- user-read-playback-position
- user-top-read
- user-read-recently-played

**Library**

- user-library-modify
- user-library-read

**Users**

- user-read-email
- user-read-private

Comment: Links are not embedded on text